# Switched website host, need old domain name to work but it won't

Tags: url, dns

I switched my website hosting to a new host and had to make a new domain name to do this, but i really need to use the old domain name as it has a lot of backlinks etc.

What do i need to do to get the website to have my old url

I have tried changing the dns with 123reg.co.uk so they point at the new website but it just returns a 404. I have tried communicating with both the host and domain registrar but the host claims i'd have to pay lots to upgrade the count and the registrar says it's nothing to do with them.

Please help as my website is down and i'm losing business.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I understand you bought your domain here 123reg.co.uk, so you should have an account. Login and change name servers that look like NS1.domain.com... NS2.domain.com to your new hosting nameservers. Make sure you registered new and old domain inside your new hosting account.

Comment: I tried updating the dns inside 123reg and it caused errors, may be i didnt give enough time for this to propagate though. Do i need to edit the details in the "zone" section on the new host. It says mail (0), @, www, *, ftp, localhost, mail, news, smtp and also above that theres my nameservers with the option to change them. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the domain over to the new host. Contact your old host and have them unlock the domain and in your account on your new host set up the domain. Then change the dns settings.

Comment: I've switched the domain name over to the people that are hosting the website, hopefully this will help me as they have better support. Thanks for the help :)